# Searching nested lists and returning index if found in Python 3.1?

Tags: python, io, nested-lists, try-except

I'm trying to work on a piece of code that deals with file input/output. The program prompts for a file name, opens it (if it exists), and reads it, one line at a time. It splits each line into separate sub-lists of a larger wordList. All of this works fine.

The part I'm having trouble with is, I'm supposed to be keeping track of how many times each word appears in the file/list. Also, the list is supposed to be unique, so the count function won't really work for me. I have a block of code that seems like it should work for me, yet it doesn't.

```
aFile = theFile.readline()
while aFile != '':
    aFile = aFile.split()
    for i in aFile:
        try:
            isInt = float(i)
            numList.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            if not wordList:
                tempList = []
                tempList.append(i)
                tempList.append(wordCount)
                wordList.append(tempList)
            else:
                for n in wordList:
                    try:
                        if i in n:
                            print ('You should see this')
                            wordIndex = wordList.index(i)
                            wordList[wordIndex][1] +=1
                    except ValueError:
                        tempList = []
                        tempList.append(i)
                        tempList.append(wordCount)
                        wordList.append(tempList)
```

This is just the block that pertains to the reading of the input file, splitting it up, and putting it into the list - or at least attempting to. As of right now, running the code results in an infinite loop where it prints "You should see this" infinitely.

If I take the second try:except loop out, it doesn't give me an infinite loop anymore, but it does give me a ValueError when the second word in the file isn't found in the wordList (as it shouldn't, since only one word had been entered before it).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I can post the rest of the code if needed.

Comment: make life easy on yourself, use `collections.Counter` to count the words.

Comment: The list of words has to be unique, so that means no duplicates - which basically renders collections.counter useless.

Comment: I quote, `"I'm supposed to be keeping track of how many times each word appears in the file/list"`, what are you counting if there are no duplicates?

Comment: There are going to be duplicates in the file, but there aren't supposed to be any in the list that's created. Admittedly, I shouldn't have put the /list, so that probably muddled things up a bit.

Comment: just use a list comp on the Counter dict keeping values that are < 2 or use a set to remove the dups from your list, I am not sure exactly what you are doing

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: It is a homework problem, I have most of the rest figured out. @Padraic - I'll look into doing that, thanks!